# Access violation error when using QTextStream to read from console

Tags: c++, qt, console-application, qtextstream

I have problem, got **access violation** when trying to use QTextStream for data reading or writing to console:

> First-chance exception at 0x77BD1D76 (ntdll.dll) in ApplicationStub.exe: 0xC0000005:
>  Access violation writing location 0x00000014.
>
> Unhandled exception at 0x77BD1D76 (ntdll.dll) in ApplicationStub.exe:
>   0xC0000005: 
> Access violation writing location 0x00000014.

**My program is simple:**

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTextStream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

        QApplication app(argc, argv);

        ///////////////////////////////////////////////CONSOLE

        QTextStream out(stdout);
        out << "Please enter login username and password\n";
        out.flush();


        QTextStream in(stdin);
        QString line;
        in >> line;

        return app.exec();

}
```

What could be the problem? 
Thanks

**Edit 1**
I also tried QCoreApplication
I am using Visual studio 2013, Windows 7

Also in my **.pro** file I have:

```
QT += console
QT += core gui
```

I have there gui for gui option, i think this should be ok.

Comment: It works for me (under linux), but i'vw changed `QApplication` to `QCoreApplication`. Did you define the project like a Console app? You should add the .pro file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem at all in the code, though it could be cleaned up quite a bit. Most likely you're not building it as a console application, thus it starts without a console, and any attempts to access the non-existent console fail.

Comments:

1. To include a Qt class `Class`, use `#include <QClass>`, not `#include <QtModule/QClass>`.
2. You can include an entire Qt module to reduce the number of explicit includes, e.g. `#include <QtCore>` would be sufficient for a console application.
3. You don't need a `QCoreApplication` instance to use `QTextStream` (note that `QApplication` is-a `QCoreApplication`!).
4. `stdout` and `stdin` come from the `<cstdio>` header. You don't need `<iostream>`.
5. In the project file as well as in your code, you don't need to add module dependencies, only the top-level modules. E.g. if you're using any module other than `core`, you don't need to explicitly add the `core` module since all other modules depend on it. If you add the `widgets` module in Qt 5, you don't need to add the `gui` module. And so on.

There are two ways to assign a console to your process:

1. Add `CONFIG += console` to the qmake project file. That way your process will always have a console window upon startup:

   ```
   # test1.pro
   QT = core
   CONFIG += console c++11
   CONFIG -= app_bundle
   TARGET = test1
   TEMPLATE = app
   SOURCES += main.cpp
   ```

   Your code will now work fine: on startup, you'll see a console window open.
2. Explicitly allocate a console in a GUI application. The console window will appear only when you need it, and not by default:

   ```
   # test1.pro
   QT = widgets      # or core if you don't care for a graphical interface
   CONFIG += c++11
   TARGET = test1
   TEMPLATE = app
   SOURCES += main.cpp
   ```

   **main.cpp**:

   ```
   #include <QtCore>
   #include <cstdio>
   #include <windows.h>

   void addConsole() {
     AllocConsole();
     freopen("CON", "wt", stdout);
     freopen("CON", "wt", stderr);
     freopen("CON", "rt", stdin);
   }

   int main() {
     addConsole();
     QTextStream out{stdout};
     QTextStream in{stdin};

     out << "Enter your name: " << flush;

     QString name;
     in >> name;
     out << "Your name is: " << name << "." << endl;
     QThread::sleep(1);
   }
   ```

#### Important Note

After making any changes to the project file, you need to re-run qmake **and** rebuild the project.

[image: context menu of the project]

To simplify this, simply erase the build folder.

Comment: Thanks, Still no working and I said, I use Visual Studio 2013, no Qt creator.

Comment: Using Visual Studio and using Qt Creator are orthogonal issues: I use Visual Studio all the time with Qt Creator, for example. You've never said that you don't use Qt Creator. You can also use qmake to use a `.pro` file to generate a Visual Studio project :) If you want a console application, set up your VS project to be a console application. If you want to control when does console appear, leave it as a windows application, and use the `addConsole` function. That's all there's to it.